# REGEX number not in a list failing with a long list

Tags: regex

I have a list of the following numbers and want a Regular expression that matches when a number is not in the list.

> 0,1,2,3,4,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,250

I have written the following REGEX statement.

```
^(?!.*(0|1|2|3|4|9|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|19|250)).*$
```

The problem is that it correctly gives a match for 5,6,7,8 etc but not for 17 or 251 for example.

I have been testing this on the online REGEX simulators.

Comment: Your pattern matches also all strings without digits, is it really what you want?

Comment: it's much easier and more flexible to use native programming language feature to check if number is not in the predefined list. What if the list comprised of 30 numbers? The regex would look ugly

Comment: you have a logical problem you don't follow the beginning with `1` or `2`, thus eliminating the possibility of 17/251 etc...

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue..

```
^(?!\D*(0|1|2|3|4|9|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|19|250)\b).*$
```

In your earlier regex you were basically saying eliminate all numbers that start with 0/1/2/3/4/9!

So your original regex would actually match 54/623/71/88 but not the others. Also the 11-19 and 250 in the list were rendered useless.

Although as others have I would also recommend you to not use regex for this, as I believe it is an overkill and a maintenance nightmare!

Also an extra note "Variable length look arounds are very inefficient too" vs regular checks.

I would do `\b\d+\b` to get each number in the string and check if they are in your list. It would be way faster.

Comment: Could be shortened to `^(?!.*(?:[0-49]|1[1-9]|250)\b).*$`

Comment: @CAustin I believe the idea is to replace `(a|b|c)` with `(d|e|f)` at a later point in time.

Comment: @CAustin `^(?!.*(?:[0-49]|1[1-689]|250)\b).*$`

Comment: The context here that these number when presented singularly will match to an error category.  But then the client has said, any other number give me a category of 'unexpected'.  This is to go in an Oracle database field.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the missing 17.

Comment: ** see below - not actually working Thanks for the answer that seems to work great.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, just tested it further and it is failing on the numbers it should be matching e.g. 34, 251

Comment: ok.  changed it to the following ^(?!.*(0|1|2|3|4|9|11|12|13|14|15|16|18|19|250)\b\d+\b).*$ and working properly.  Thanks very much

Comment: I changed the regex to check only the first occuring number in a line, see working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/bxt6XR/1).

Comment: @RonnieRocket try [this](https://regex101.com/r/bxt6XR/2). It rejects all lines if any of the numbers in the given list appear anywhere in the line!

Comment: @bulbus Thankyou.  This seems to do what I was wanting, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the discard technique by matching what you do not want and capturing what you really want.

You can use a regex like this:

```
\b(?:[0-49]|1[1-689]|250)\b|(\d+)
```

Here you can check a working demo where in blue you have the matches (what you don't want) and in green the content you want. Then you have to grab the content from the capturing group

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qKmLMB/1)**

[image]

Not sure what regex engine you are using, but here I created a sample using java:
https://ideone.com/B7kLe0

Comment: This one does not seem to work.  It matches with everything even the ones I want to exclude https://regex101.com/r/UGCw8I/1

Comment: @RonnieRocket as I posted in the answer it matches everything but it captures what you want. This is a regex technique to match/discard and capture/save. The key is to bring the content from the capturing group `$1`. Check the example i posted. In your link, you can see that green matches are the one you want and the blue the discarded